# Can I use same OEM key on same machine after replacing my hdd to ssd?

Tags: windows-10, oem

I want to replace my hdd drive to ssd drive but i have OEM key of windows professional installed on my laptop?
So can i use same OEM after changing my hard drive to SSD?

Comment: Yes, if you have an OEM license key, then that will still work on another HD or SS drive on the same machine. The OEM license is tied to the motherboard of the machine so you are fine to replace hard drives in that same machine all day long with OEM license I believe. It might be much timelier to make a full image backup and then push that to your new SD though.

Comment: Yes, you can either image you current install (with Pro version or better) and use a startup/repair disk to load the image on your new drive, or you can download a fresh W10 image from MS and install it and then type in your license key. A drive change generally won't trigger a license issue.